# Is there a TeX font containing Egyptological Alef and Ayn?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I am looking for a TeX font going smoothly with Computer Modern that contains the four characters Capital/Lowercase Egyptological Alef/Ayn (UNicode points U+A722...U+A725).

I have searched Scott Pakin's [comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FreeSerif` works, and comes with `TeXLive`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
The character {\fontspec{FreeSerif}Ꜣ} is quite strange
\end{document}
```

Typeset with `XeLaTeX`. This yields:

[image]

I found it by using [FileFormat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/A722/fontsupport.htm).

Comment: .. and the FreeSerif interpretation of it is even more strange, I expected something like the "right half of digit 3"

Comment: @jknappen I interpreted "going smoothly with Computer Modern" as "from a serif typeface", since CM has serifs (I suppose my ignorance in Egyptology is showing!). Going through the [different interpretations of A722](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/A722/fontsupport.htm), it seems serif typefaces interpret it similarly to `FreeSerif` (two disconnected pieces with heavy terminals), whereas sans serif ones have one connected piece of constant weight, more like the "right half of digit 3".

Comment: Going back to the sources: Here is the original proposal for the Egyptological characters to UNicode: http://std.dkuug.dk/JTC1/SC2/wg2/docs/n2241.pdf – "going smoothly with Computer Modern" basically means "being compatible in size and weight"